# Unable to set gradient on uiview using layer

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, calayer

I have set color for uicontrollerview from stroyboard but I want gradient in the background color. So coded the required layer in viewdidappear still its not appearing.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self setBackGradient];
}

-(void)setBackGradient{
    CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    grad.frame = self.view.bounds;

    UIColor *topColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.91 green:0.94 blue:0.99 alpha:1.0];
    UIColor *bottomColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.67 green:0.80 blue:0.93 alpha:1.0];

    NSArray *colorsArr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:topColor,bottomColor, nil];
    grad.colors=colorsArr;
    grad.masksToBounds=YES;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: What is the background color of your view? try to set it transparent before adding the layer

Comment: tried clearcolor from IB but not working it is showing black background.

Answer (score 0):

The colors for a layer need to be `CGColor`s. Try the following:

```
-(void)setBackGradient{

    CAGradientLayer *grad = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    grad.frame = self.view.bounds;

    NSArray *colorsArr=@[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.91 green:0.94 blue:0.99 alpha:1.0].CGColor, (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.67 green:0.80 blue:0.93 alpha:1.0].CGColor];
    grad.colors=colorsArr;
    grad.masksToBounds=YES;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:grad atIndex:0];

}
```